# What's a good java-friendly in-memory map supporting range queries?

Tags: java, data-structures, key-value-store

I'm looking for an in-memory map with java-friendly APIs (not necessarily java) that supports range queries. Our design doesn't yet call for it to be distributed.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I was going to suggest `TreeMap`, but I have a suspicion that you're asking about something else?

Comment: @NPE a treemap would do, I'm just not too convinced on how efficient a range query in it is. Other posters have also suggested it, so I'll go into the details of it. Thanks!!

Comment: Depends what you mean by "range queries," but [Guava's `RangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). A range query can be done using the methods `lowerEntry` and `higherEntry`, `higherKey` and `lowerKey`. Find the first key smaller than the left end of the range, the first key bigger than the right one and return everything between them.

Comment: Great. I wasn't sure that a `TreeMap` would be optimized for range queries. I'll check it in detail then. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, any class that implements the `NavigableMap` interface will do. For now, only `TreeMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` implement this interface in the stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how flexible you need things to be and how extensible, etc., you could consider using an in-memory database; that would give you far more capability than you've mentioned here, and is probably only interesting if you think you might have a use for a lot more one day.  You would be expending a lot of complexity, and possibly space, for something that would be extremely flexible.  But you should be aware that several (free) java databases offer in-memory configurations, including Derby (released with Java).

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the purpose of comparing raw performance with a previous implementation, I wanted to quickly prototype with a simple structure. I think it's certainly a good idea to move into a full-fledged KVS right after. I was also curious as to how those KVS' would go about supporting range queries

Answer (score 1):

Is an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) maybe what you're looking for?

Comment: Definitely worth looking into it. I think it doesn't fit my specific problem, but it certainly fits the question. Thanks!